Spring cloud stream binder - several bindings with same processor
I use spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams version 4.0.3, I have an arbitrary amount of topics,
e.g:

topic-in-1, topic-in-2, topic-in-3

and

topic-out-1, topic-out-2, topic-out-3

and one common processing function, something like this:
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> trace() {
    return input -> input.peek((key, value) -> log.trace("Record processed {}", value));
}

I want to build 3 streams:

topic-in-1 > trace > topic-out-1


topic-in-2 > trace > topic-out-2


topic-in-3 > trace > topic-out-3

or 2:

topic-in-1, topic-in-2 > trace > topic-out-1


topic-in-3 > trace > topic-out-2

And may be there will be more of them, topic-out-4..5..6..7.. etc
I know that I can put multiple topics into destination property,
But is there a way to configure spring to use same processor/function to build processing for each topic independently? I cannot add new function with same functionality every time I want to add new stream from topic-in-N to topic-out-N, there has to be a way to reuse it.
I cannot do this..
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition:  trace
    stream:
      bindings:
        trace-in-0:
          destination: topic-in-1
          group: test_group_1
        trace-out-0:
          destination: topic-out-1
        trace2-in-0: #?
          destination: topic-in-2
          group: test_group_2
        trace2-out-0:
          destination: topic-in-2 # I want to write to topic-in-2, and then add some more

Thank you

As a solution, on service start I read my configs and create new beans of Function type, then I just use these functions to build as much independent pipelines as I want.

This is an interesting idea for a new feature. You can address this by using function composition, but still, that is not an elegant solution. I agree that the framework should support this and created an issue to address this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2950

@sobychacko thank you, btw I couldn't find an easy way to declare arbitrary functions at will, I had to register it as new AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition(Function.class) via BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor. I tried FunctionRegistration class, but it didn't' work as I expected. It would be great to have such ability.

Could you clarify what you mean by "arbitrary functions"? Maybe comment on that GH issue I created?

Can you comment on the issue we created and see if you can provide more context around your use case? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2950
